# JavaScript get specific access to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a JSON Array in following format :

["url1.de","url2.de","url3.de"....]

phpScript

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
        <tr><td>".$row["Number"]."</td><td>".$row["MusikName"]." ".$row["MusikURL"]."</td></tr>";


             $urlarray[]=$row["MusikURL"];


              $zufall = array_rand($urlarray);

              echo "
              <br /> <b>URL:</b> " . $urlarray[$i];  // echo URL : www.url1.de  URL:www.url2.de ...





              $jsarray = json_encode($urlarray,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); 




              $i++;
        }            
        echo $jsarray; // ["url1.de","url2.de"...
```

JavaScript

```
        var url = new Array();




        var urlamount = ' <?php echo $i; ?>;';

        url = ' <?php echo json_encode($jsarray); ?>;';

        alert(urlamount);


        alert(url); // "["url1.de","url2.de"...
         alert(url[1]); // I expected he will alert url1.de but he only alert single letters...in this case 'u'
        var audio = new Audio(url[x]);

        audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
        }, false);

        audio.play();

    }
```

I try to gain an url  via url[x] x should be a random value between urlamount...
Or are there other ways to save the urls from  $urlarray[] to a JavaScript Array ?

thanks in advance !!

Comment: ["url1.de","url2.de","url3.de"....] its not JSON array

Comment: `var arr = <?php echo json_encode(["url1.de","url2.de","url3.de"]); ?>;alert(arr[0]);` works, I assume you have another problem in your script.

Comment: I am able to alert the hole url but like this -> "["url1.de","url2.de"... Could this be a problem ? Instead of ["url1.de","url2.de"...

Comment: [link](http://paste2.org/6NsXwUmX) I uploaded the source ... but as far as I know there isn't something which could be the problem

Comment: Remove the quotes `'` in `url = ' <?php echo json_encode($jsarray); ?>;'`

Comment: @Meiko It alerts in this case only -> [ <-

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript code with below code

```
var urlamount = '<?php echo rand(0,(sizeof($jsarray)-1)); ?>';
var url_json = '<?php echo json_encode($jsarray,true); ?>';
var url = $.parseJSON(url_json);
alert(urlamount);
alert(url[urlamount]);
```

Comment: 1. There is no `jQuery` tag;  2. `urlamount` is the number of urls and not a random integer 3. After fixing `url` there is no need for `urlamout` as the number of elements can be obtained with `url.length`

Comment: thanks Andreas changed it to .length ...thanks Amit for your help (i will research $.parseJSON) but this didn't work either :/ If I press the submit button the JavaScript will not be executed